# What is the best way to deal with MySql database in single-page-app?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, angularjs, backbone.js

What is the best way to deal with complicated MySql database professionally in single-page-app?

I am usually using jQuery ajax to fetch data from the database, but it seems to be too slow while retrieving the data into the browser.

That always happens when I use `keydown` behavior to get values from database, also when I change dropdown menu values from PHP files according to another dropdown value on `change` e.g. Country > City

My Code is like:

JS

```
input.keydown(function(){

    var val = $(this).value()

        $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
            url: "results.php",   
            data: form.serialize(),
            async: false,
            success : function(data)
            {
                $('.results').append(data);
            }
        })

    }

});
```

That sometimes make the browser freezing for moments in case I have a complicated query.

Should I use Ajax? or try using another framework like Angular.js or even Backbone?

Please advise.

Comment: those frameworks will still use ajax. What is the specific problem that is `slow`? Also define what slow means in time value

Comment: I suspect that your bottleneck is in your SQL query - so changing your method of data retrieval won't likely do much in helping you. If your data is not relational, it might make more sense to use a non-relational database such as MongoDB

Comment: This question needs some improvement. Such as, here is my query, schema, and gosh can anyone help me make it fast, something

Comment: @Drew the question has been improved

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated the question

Comment: Setting async to false is what is blocking your browser. I would get and store all these values in chunks on page load or action. For example return all the countries on page load, then when someone picks a country do one call for the cities and save them locally. Hitting the server on every key press will be extremely taxing to your server / database. But to answer your question I would recommend AngularJS but I have heard good things about React as well.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't comment on your SQL slowdown without seeing what you're doing server-side, the issue with your page freezing is more straightforward, and has nothing to do with the server itself.

As David Jones' comment mentions above, you're preventing the browser from executing anything else until that call returns, as you have 'async' disabled on your AJAX call.

Server processing aside, IO over the network (ie, the AJAX call itself) is a very slow event compared to executing code, or even likely your SQL call. Most of the time is spent waiting for the request to complete the round trip.

The reason that Javascript is built around an asynchronous event loop is precisely to avoid situations like this (the first letter in AJAX stands for "asynchronous").

I would focus on your front end, and not have it wait for the call to complete. The question above doesn't give any context as to why you're setting async to false, but if it's because you'd otherwise be making too many server calls (one for every keydown), try using something like [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) to limit the calls you make to the backend.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what big platforms like Facebook relies on? Are they relying on Ajax and MySql?

Comment: No problem! I can't say what Facebook uses specifically, but MySQL is used widely in production by many, many people and it does work well. YouTube and Twitter have used it extensively, alongside other technologies.

At a certain size you'd have to consider advanced topics like sharding and replication, but that's at a very high amount of queries. When you reach that point, see:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-book-on-back-end-architecture-for-large-scale-web-applications

Comment: Also, if you want to ever see just how much AJAX is used out in the wild, open up your dev console when using GMail =)